# How to configure session based timout options in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP based internal web application that I created a simple login system for and am using session_start() to initiliaze the $_SESSION object and checking other pages in the web directory if the user has been logged in or not. If not give the standard 403 if so load the page.

Now the way we have the webpage setup is a standard consistent front page which hosts the login, and the navigation menu to access the other pages. The body of this front page and all its contents is what changes using POST/API options to dictate which page is to be shown, ex: [www.example.com/frontPage.php?page=someOtherWebpage](http://www.example.com/frontPage.php?page=someOtherWebpage)

It is on the frontPage.php page that I create a session and allow the user the login before loading the appropriate frontPage body content. From here between $_POST and $_SESSION I can access the necessary information to decide whether a user is allowed access to various parts of the web directory.

Now this is where I'm unsure if I am doing this correctly. In order to maintain security integrity every individual web page in root has a session_start() in it too, so it can pull $_SESSION and check if a variable I declared called "LOGGED" is true or false. If false, 403, etc. This was done so that if someone who does not have a login but somehow accesses or knows the direct URL to some of these webpages, they cannot access it without logging in. This feels like the right solution to me, and for now it works as if I try to navigate directly to any given page in my web directory without logging in I get the 403. There might be better or more standardized way of doing this and I'm open to suggestions of course, and a more 'standardized' way might be the solution to my problem that I'm finally going to describe.

When a user logs in, we haven't time it exactly, but somewhere between 15-45 minutes they have to log in again. On frontPage.php I tried to set the cookie_lifetime to a day in seconds (86400), I also checked my php.ini file for these settings:

**oci8.persistent_timeout** - for allowing idle persistent connetions, we have it set to -1 to indicate forever

**session.cookie_lifetime** - the default server configuration for cookie lifetime is currently set to 0 which is until browser restart.

**session.gc_maxlifetime** - garbage collection maximum lifetime for when data stored is considered trash and cleaned up (this is where I expect I need to make changes but I'm not familiar enough with garbage cleaning to know how this interacts with cookies and their lifetimes) its currently set to 1440 or 24 minutes so this falls in the expected time frame

Is the gc_maxlifetime the config option I'm looking to increase in order to prevent someone from being kicked due to inactivity? Or is there something inherently wrong with how we've set up our sessions? Or some other reason or option that I haven't considered/am unaware of?

If it is important to someone's answer we use LDAP to log in communicating with our local AD server and checking user, pass, and AD groups.

I appreciate any answers anyone can provide.

Thank you.

Comment: We setup an AJAX script on a page one time where we wanted users to keep their session alive longer. The JS would ping the server so many times every so many minutes, lengthening the session to a couple hours, when on the specific page. Everyone else, or when on other pages, kept the shorter idle timeout.

Comment: Jared, that's not a bad thought. It makes me wonder though how garbage collection and the 'idle' timeout interact with one another. But I think the biggest problem is that when one of my users who has sat on a page for X amount of inactive time then navigates to a second page per the testing process then when it tries to pull the login status check there is nothing to pull because GC deleted it. However I'm not sure if GC deletes only data associated with inactive sessions? If keeping the session active with AJAX prevents GC then that could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically sessions should be short-lived (*30 minutes is the default*). The issue you tend to face with longer session lifetime is that they become vulnerable to collisions. Especially on a busy server with lots of sessions. PHP has no protection against session collisions. This problem can be exploited with a simple DoS attack by say cURLing any page on your site that generates a session in a loop. If they can flood your session storage with enough sessions they increase the probability of collision and thus obtaining an already active session. PHP won't validate if the randomly generated session id. So if a `session_start()` happens to generate the same session id as an existing one it will return an already existing session id to the user thereby granted them access to that session data.

There is also the possibility of a session fixation problem wherein the user can obtain a session that does not revalidate idempotent data. You can use [`session_create_id()`](https://www.php.net/function.session-create-id) to help prevent this type of vulnerability in PHP 7.1.

> **session_create_id()** is used to create new session id for the current
> session. It returns collision free session id.
>
> If session is not active, collision check is omitted.
>
> Session ID is created according to php.ini settings.
>
> It is important to use the same user ID of your web server for GC task
> script. Otherwise, you may have permission problems especially with
> files save handler.

Though there is no protection against collision attacks baked in. Just mitigation. So usually the idea is to keep `gc.max_lifetime` fairly low and consider that this also can affect things like DoS attacks against the garbage collection problem which in PHP is pretty bad in the default file session save handler.

Comment: So within the context of mitigating (as much as possible) attacks against our web application what is the best method to keeping sessions active for longer than the typical 30 minutes without creating 'too many' or 'too harsh' of vulnerabilities? The context is that we run tests off of this site frequently. Something around every 45 minutes or so the program needs to be accessed to interact with said given tests. I'd prefer my guys not have to log in every 45 minutes. Increasing gc_max_lifetime does this but you helped me realize I may need to reconsider.

Comment: Well if you factor in the collision rate rate of the hash (birthday problem) and the mximum lifetime of thr session you find a sweet spot based your servers load average. So say you get on average 1K requests per second. If you were to have the default php session settings (32 bit hash with 30 min gc.max_lifetime) then the probability of collision is about 1 in 100K. This is usually pretty safe for the average website. But say load increases by an order of magnitude and the mac lifetime is also increased to 24 Hours. Now all of a sudden your probability of collision is reduced to 1 in 250 req.

Comment: So the idea is to stay as far away from longer session lifetimes and smaller entropy spaces (hash size, hash algo, source of entropy) as load increases.

Comment: This is incredibly useful input so thank you for taking the time Sherif. Fortunately this web app is super small. Used only by our engineering lab primarily and by less than 10 people at that. It also is not available outside of our network without intentional penetrative work.

Comment: You're welcome. Then you should be okay with increasing the lifetime just try not to gover 24 hours as thats usually the sweet spot.